# "Unexpected token &" when parsing Rails array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In Rails if fill an array like this:

```
@my_array << ["A", "B", "C"]
```

This array is used in `graph.html.erb` to use as input for a graph:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @my_array %>);
```

But this gives me the error `Unexpected token &`, because the array looks like this in the browser:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([[&quot;A&quot;, &quot;B&quot;, &quot;C&quot;]);
```

How can I make sure the quotes are like normal quotes? I tried to use this, but that dowsn't make any difference:

```
@my_array << ["A".html_safe, "B".html_safe, "C".html_safe]
```

Comment: Try escape javascript (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html). Embedded code should look like: <%= j @my_array %>

Comment: That gives an error: ``undefined method `gsub' for #<Array``

Answer (score 0):

It's always advisable to use rails' inbuilt #to_json methods for this, which exist for strings, arrays, hashes, and your ActiveRecord classes.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @my_array.to_json %>);
```

Comment: In my case, I had to add `.html_safe`. Otherwise, the quotes were changed to "&quot;".

Answer (score 0):

I used [Rails#raw](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) so `<%= %>` wont try to escape the array string and add the `&` characters:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= raw @my_array %>);
```

Comment: note that this is a security vulnerability. what if your array contains the string `</script>`  ?

Comment: I'm the only one adding to my array, so I can avoid problematic terms.  This worked perfectly for me.